# Disable voting for closed questions.

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, voting, closed-questions

Because it is closed for some reasons.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this question... ^_^ ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.

Just because a question *is* closed doesn't mean it *should* be closed. As on other SE sites, questions will get closed and reopened all the time, and upvotes on closed questions are a tool that allows members of the community that don't yet have the rep to directly vote to close/reopen to express their view that it is, in fact, a good question.

Comment: +1. Nothing more to add.